# Using sum with multiple inner joins

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a couple of tables which I want to select from. I want to also use a sum() on one of the tables. Here is what I've got so far.

```sql
DROP TABLE ... IF EXISTS
CREATE TABLE ... IF EXISTS AS
    SELECT
        fbp.*
        bcs.yyyy_mm_dd,
        cspd.*,
    FROM xxx.fbp fbp
    INNER JOIN table2 st ON (fbp.id = st.xml_id)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN (field1) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE SUM(field1)
            END AS field1
         FROM table2 bcs
         WHERE yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-04-21'
         GROUP BY bcs.column_id
    ) AS bcs ON bcs.column_id = fbp.id
    INNER JOIN table3 cspd ON (fbp.id = cspd.id)
    WHERE bcs.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-04-21'
    AND cspd.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-04-21'
    AND (st.id IN (9)) AND (st.date IS NULL);
```

When I run this query, I get the following error.

> Expression not in GROUP BY key 'field1'.

When I add `field1` to the GROUP BY, I get a different error.

I'm looking for my dataset to be the sum(field1) grouped by the hotel_id and then the other metrics which I have selected. That should give me a daily sum along with some other metadata. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below.

```
DROP TABLE ... IF EXISTS
CREATE TABLE ... IF EXISTS AS
    SELECT
        fbp.*
        bcs.yyyy_mm_dd,
        cspd.*,
    FROM xxx.fbp fbp
    INNER JOIN table2 st ON (fbp.id = st.xml_id)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            column_id
            sum(CASE
                WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE field1
            END) AS field1
         FROM table2 bcs
         WHERE yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-04-21'
         GROUP BY bcs.column_id
    ) AS bcs ON bcs.column_id = fbp.id
    INNER JOIN table3 cspd ON (fbp.id = cspd.id)
    WHERE bcs.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-04-21'
    AND cspd.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-04-21'
    AND (st.id IN (9)) AND (st.date IS NULL);
```

Comment: This seems to throw a ParseException on the sum case. ParseException line 27:27 extraneous input ')' expecting KW_END near '<EOF>'

Comment: Can you try now

Comment: Hi @Vijiy, that seems to work. However, now I get Invalid column reference 'yyyy_mm_dd'. Do you have any idea why? I suspect it might have something to do with the aggregation or grouping. This column is a partition.

Comment: You need to add required column in select clause of table2 and in group by clause